# How do i get my link text to not run outside of the Div?

Tags: html, css, web

https://jsfiddle.net/LnbcfmL3/

Html

```
<div class="Nav">
            <a href="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Computer Science\Rugby_Arguement.html"> Rugby Arguement </a>
        </div>
        <div class="Nav">
            <a href="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Computer Science\Football_Arguement.html"> Football Arguement </a>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.Nav{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
border-radius: 100px / 50px;
border: 2px solid black;
left: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px /50px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FF6600;
}
a{
text-align: center;
}
```

That's what I've got so far and the link text in my ovals is running out of the div itself. I've tried things suggested in other questions for about 2 hours now and nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add: *overlfow: hidden* to your .Nav class.

Comment: position your `a`  `absolute`ly inside the `Nav`

Answer (score 0):

If you position 'a' absolutely, and add top and bottom positions, you can achieve what you want.

```
a {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 30px;
left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jsfiddle below, how does that look?

what i did was change the `width` and change position of the `<a>` tag

https://jsfiddle.net/mk8xx5zg/

Hope this helps.

Here you can learn more about the position property in css: 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

A more dynamic approach can be achieved by utilizing `display:flex`

```
.Nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

By using the above declarations on the parent element, child elements will now be center both vertically and horizontally (regardless of size, thus no hard positioning or size values required)

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LnbcfmL3/1/

[A great Flexbox tutorial by css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)